# android-Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > File google-services.json is missing

Tags: android

i am newbie to android developnment. i am trying to integrate firebase cloud messaging notification service in my app.According to guidelines mentioned in  https://firebase.google.com/, i added google-services.json file in my app folder but still i am getting this error saying "File google-services.json missing module root..".please help me out.
Below is my Build.gradle(project level) file:-

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(app level):-

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mohit.munjal.firebasenotifications"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'

 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 })
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.> File 
google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot 
function without it. 
Searched Location: 
D:\Android studio projects\FirebaseCloudMessagingApp\app\src\debug\google-
services.json
D:\Android studio projects\FirebaseCloudMessagingApp\app\google-
services.json
```

Comment: make sure that you have adde google_services.json file in the same directory where your project level gradle is.. i.e. Inside app folder

Comment: thanks for your reply but its at right place. Although i jus solved it by connecting firebase from android studio ie by clicking on tools->firebase and so on..So now i dont need to place google-services.json file explicitly in my project i guess

Comment: hehe.. great! happy coding